# Issue with Sticky Div as a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mustache

I had a request for a Table layout with a sticky header if the user scrolls down far enough for the Div Header to not be visible.

Problem:
The methodology implemented works fine, except that the table columns go out of alignment when the `position: fixed` is applied.

Mustache:

```
<div class="GridView">
    <div class="RowHeader">
        <div class="RowItem vertical-bottom">
            <div class="HeaderCell RowCell RankCol"><span title="Index">Rank</span></div>
            <div class="HeaderCell RowCell PriorityCol vertical-bottom">
                <label>Priority</label>
            </div>
            <div class="HeaderCell RowCell MagnitudeCol vertical-bottom">
                <label>Magnitude</label>
            </div>
            <div class="HeaderCell RowCell FinancialCol vertical-bottom">
                <label>Financial Impact</label>
            </div>
            <div class="HeaderCell RowCell DollarCol vertical-bottom">
                <label>Dollar Impact</label>
            </div>
            <div class="HeaderCell RowCell DueDateCol DateColumn">
                <label>Due Date</label>
            </div>
            <div class="HeaderCell RowCell ClientCol ellipsis">
                <label>Client</label>
            </div>
            <div class="HeaderCell RowCell TaskCol ellipsis">
                <label>Task</label>
            </div>
            <div class="HeaderCell RowCell RequestorCol ellipsis">
                <label>Requestor</label>
            </div>
            <div class="HeaderCell RowCell CreatedDateCol DateColumn">
                <label>Created Date</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="RowBody">
        {{#.}}
        <div id="tr{{ID}}" class="RowItem">
            <div class="RowCell RankCol">
                <div class="SortIndex {{DueDateStatus}}">
                    <input id="Input_Text_{{ID}}" class="DragHandle Label {{DueDateStatus}}" type="text" value="{{Rank}}"
                        onclick="javascript:Input_Click(this, {{ID}});" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="RowCell PriorityCol vertical-bottom">
                <img title="{{PriorityImageFilename}}" src="Images/{{PriorityImageFilename}}.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="RowCell MagnitudeCol ellipsis">
                <label title="{{OrderOfMagnitude}}">{{OrderOfMagnitude}}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="RowCell FinancialCol ellipsis">
                <label title="{{FinancialImpact}}">{{FinancialImpact}}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="RowCell DollarCol ellipsis">
                <label title="{{DollarImpactFormat}}">{{DollarImpactFormat}}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="RowCell DueDateCol DateColumn">
                <label title="{{DueDate}}">{{DueDate}}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="RowCell ClientCol ellipsis" onclick="javascript:Table_Row_Click(this, {{ID}}, '{{Task}}');">
                <label title="{{ClientName}}">{{ClientName}}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="RowCell TaskCol ellipsis" onclick="javascript:Table_Row_Click(this, {{ID}}, '{{Task}}');">
                <label title="{{Description}}">{{{Task}}}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="RowCell RequestorCol ellipsis" onclick="javascript:Table_Row_Click(this, {{ID}}, '{{Task}}');">
                <label title="{{Requestor}}">{{Requestor}}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="RowCell CreatedDateCol DateColumn">
                <label title="{{CreatedDate}}">{{CreatedDate}}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{/.}}
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    &.GridView {
        display: inline-table;
        table-layout:fixed;
        margin: 0px;
        width:100%;

        .DateColumn {
            width: 90px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: $FontSize - 1;
        }

        .GeneralColumn {

        }
    }

    &.RowHeader {
        display: table-header-group;
        background-color: $BGPrimary;

        &.sticky {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
        }

        > .RowItem {
            > .HeaderCell {
                border: $StdBorder;
            }
        }

        .HeaderCell {
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
        }

        label {
            margin: 0px;
        }
    }

    &.RowBody {
        display: table-row-group;
        background-color: $BGRowNormal;

        .RowItem {
            > .RowCell {
                border: $StdBorder;
            }

            &:hover {
                background-color: $BGRowHover;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            &.selected {
                background-color: $BGRowSelected;
            }
        }
    }

    &.RowItem {
        display: table-row;

        > .RowCell {
            display: table-cell;
        }
    }

    .RankCol {
        width: ($idxColWidth);
    }

    .PriorityCol{
        width: 55px;
        padding: 1px;
        text-align: center;

        label {
            margin: 0px;
        }
    }

    .MagnitudeCol {
        width: 110px;

        @media screen and (max-width: 1014px) {
            display:none !important;    
        }
    }

    .FinancialCol {
        width: 90px;

        @media screen and (max-width: 1014px) {
            display:none !important;    
        }
    }

    .DollarCol {
        width: 90px;
        text-align: right;
    }

    .ClientCol{
        width: 150px;
    }

    .TaskCol{
        min-width: 160px;
    }

    .RequestorCol{
        width:100px;
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (typeof $stickyEl !== 'undefined') {
        $stickyEl.toggleClass('sticky', $(window).scrollTop() > elTop);
    }
});

LoadTaskGridView(src.value, function () {
    $stickyEl = $('.RowHeader');
    elTop = $stickyEl.offset().top;
});
```

When the `.RowHeader` is in view (not at top of the window), then all the columns of the table design are aligned and correctly displayed.

As soon as the `.RowHeader` meets the requirement for the `$(window).scroll(....)`, then it doesn't retain its current width of the screen.

Normal Image:
[image]

Problem Image:

- Minimum Resolution:
  [image]
- Full Resolution:
  [image]

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle for this? That would be quite useful

Comment: Unsure of how to do that with Mustache even with a dummy set.  As well, most of the actual implementation is governed by HIPAA

Comment: If you have a look at you column widths - some of the headers are larger than the actual widths you've set so when the header is detached, you css widths will kick in on the rest of the table.  Ensure your widths fit your header in and it should fix your problem.  If it doesn't there are plenty of easy to use [table plugins](http://www.sitepoint.com/30-amazing-jquery-tables/) that you can use and will be easier than writing your own

Comment: Give me a second, working on JSON Generator to create a Fiddle.

Comment: You can try and use this plugin http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/09/sticky-table-headers-columns/

Comment: I have a Table HTML template that works, aside from the fact the header is not fixed.  Wanted to work against my gut and use DIV Table design.

Comment: Ended up using http://codepen.io/jgx/pen/wiIGc for the idea for Table implementation.  Had to modify that implementation for my specific need but was a good starting line.